# Overload += for a template?

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading, overloading

I have a base class `Animal` and a derived class `Bird : Animal`. I use a template class that will store vectors of pointers to either `Animal` or `Bird` objects. I want to overload the `+=` operator in such a way that I can insert a new `animal` right in the `Atlas`, so `m_length = m_length + 1`, `pages.push_back(animal)`, just to get the idea.

Here's my template class:

```cpp
template <class T>
class Atlas2 {
 public:
  int m_length;
  std::list<T> pages;
  Atlas2() { m_length = 0; }
  ~Atlas2() {}
  void adauga(T data);
  T operator+=(const T& data) {
    this->m_length++;
    this->pages.push_back(data);
    return *this;
  };
};
```

And here's the `Animal`/`Bird` classes:

```cpp
class Animal {
 protected:
  std::string m_name;

 public:
  Animal() {}
  Animal(std::string name) : m_name{name} {}
  virtual void set_name(std::string name) { m_name = name; }
  virtual std::string get_name() { return m_name; }
  virtual std::string regn() const { return "???"; }

  virtual ~Animal() { cout << "Destructor animal" << '\n'; }
};

class Bird : public Animal {
 public:
  bird() : animal() {}
  bird(std::string name) : Animal{name} {}
  void set_name(std::string nume) { m_name = nume; }

  std::string get_name() { return m_name; }

  std::string regn() const override { return "pasare"; }
  ~bird() { cout << "destructor pasare" << '\n'; }
};
```

However, I can't figure this out. When I use the overloaded `+=` operator in `main()` like this:

```cpp
Pasare *c = new Pasare{"vulture"};
Atlas2<Animal *> Atlas;
Atlas += c;
```

It shows me an error, that it couldn't convert `Atlas<Animal *>` to `<Animal*>`.

How should I implement this correctly? Any tip?

Note: The template works fine, I can store in my list pointers to either `Animal` or `Birds` without problems, and access their specific methods. I just can't figure out the `+=` part.

Comment: `m_length` is redundant, you can use `pages.size()` when needed. But more importantly, what is `pagini`? And `Pasare`? Please show *real* code. And also, please show the *actual* error message verbatim.

Comment: @remy oh my bad, i forgot to translate those. Pagini, pasare = pages, bird in romanian.
Thanks for the tip with `size`. Question was answered, i was returning a <t> object instead of an Atlas2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that you've declared your `operator+=` as returning a `T`, but the `return` statement in it is `return *this;`, which is an `Atlas2<T>`.

If you change the return type to `Atlas2<T> &`, it should work.  That's what you would normally want to return from an `operator+=` anyways, though with your use, it doesn't matter much as you're ignoring the returned value.

Answer (score 4):

You should return `Atlas2<T> &` not `T`:

```
Atlas2<T>& operator+=(const T& data) {
    this->m_length++;
    this->pagini.push_back(data);
    return *this;
};
```